# How to Set HOURS and Minutes from a table into a timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

Lets say I have a table which storing HOURS and MINUTES in two different column.
For example:

```
HOURS|MINUTES 
------------------
1|11
2|22
3|33
```

How can I merge the hours and minutes in my table into current timestamp

My concept are as below

```
SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) + HOURS + MINUTES FROM MYTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of trying i find out that i need to further enhance my table design, instead of storing minute and hours in different column, is better that i store in in single column. The sample value can be '18:36:00'

then use the following query to convert it

```
(SELECT CAST(? AS TIMESTAMP) + HOUR(TIME(END_TIMESTAMP)) HOURS + MINUTE(TIME(END_TIMESTAMP)) MINUTES FROM MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

try this **[one](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=255855)**

```
 select current timestamp + HOURS hour + MINUTES  minute 
 from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: SELECT TRUNC(CURRENT TIMESTAMP) + START_HOUR_OF_DAY HOURS + START_MINUTES MINUTES FROM MY_TABLE;

this wont work